# Hibernate: joining with one of the keys of a multi-keyed table

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-onetomany

I've got a table Category and a table TranslatableText. The category is like this

```
create table Category (
  id int not null,
  parent_id int default 0,
  TranslatableDescriptionId int default 1,
  primary key(id));

create table TranslatableText (
  id int not null,
  lang enum ('NO','EN','FR'),
  text mediumtext,
  primary key(id, lang));
```

In my Category entity I've defined a mapping:

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="TranslatableDescriptionId")
@ForeignKey(name="FK_TranslatableTextId")
private Set<TranslatableText> translatableText;
```

But when it executes, it tries to access TranslatableDescriptionId, not id. Even if the TranslatableText entity has defined

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@Id
@Column(name = "lang", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private String lang;

@Column(name = "text", length = 400, nullable = false)
private String text;
```

The query with the incorrect name selected:

select translatab0_.TranslatableDescriptionId as Translat4_13_1_, translatab0_.id as id1_, translatab0_.lang as Lang1_, translatab0_.id as id22_0_, translatab0_.lang as Lang22_0_, translatab0_.text as Text22_0_ from tblTranslateableText translatab0_ where translatab0_.TranslatableDescriptionId in ('126', '119', '103', '116', '121', '107', '113', '101', '109', '105', '123', '106', '125', '124', '114')

If I change the mappings @JoinColumn to read

```
@JoinColumn(name="TranslatableDescriptionId", referencedColumnName="id")
```

I get the following error when loading my app:

org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(Category) and its related supertables and secondary tables

For good measure I also tried:

```
@JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="TranslatableDescriptionId")
```

That gave me the error:

org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: TranslatableDescriptionId in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(Category) and its related supertables and secondary tables

Any suggestions to what I should do? I really want Category's translateableText to contain all the translations for its description, so I really want to join Category.TranslatableDescriptionId==TranslatableText.id

UPDATE1:
TranslatableText is used by many entities, so putting in a categoryId in it and reversing the relationship is not an option.

UPDATE2:
I was able to load it saying `@JoinColumn(name="id")`, but this led to a ClassCastException in Hibernate where it, instead of having an Integer as a key, has an Array containing a single Integer as a key. This fails to be made into a String and thus proper SQL. So it's probably still not the mapping I want

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of mapping is possible, but not very convenient because you'll have to manage identity of `TranslatableText`s manually (that's why Hibernate complains about non-mapped column `TranslatableDescriptionId`):

```
public class Category implements Serializable {
    ...
    private Long translatableDescriptionId;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="TranslatableDescriptionId") 
    private Set<TranslatableText> translatableText;
    ...
}
```

So, you need to manually assign unique `translatableDescriptionId`s to all "targets" of `TranslatableText` (categories, items, folders as you say) and manually set this values as `id` of `TranslatableText` before persisting it (you can't just add `TranslatableText` into the `Set`).

--

However, the more convenient design is to introduce an intermediate entity to keep the identity of all transalations attatched to a specific target:

```
public class Category {
    ...
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "targetId")
    private TranslationTarget target;
}

public class TranslationTarget {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "targetId")
    private Set<TranslatableText> texts;
}
```

-

```
create table Category (              
  targetId int,
  ...);        

create table TranslationTargets (
  id int primary key
);      

create table TranslatableText (              
  targetId int not null,              
  lang enum ('NO','EN','FR'),              
  text mediumtext,              
  primary key(targetId, lang));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that design out right away and report back :-)  I'm confused a bit, however, since the way I read it I am merely pushing the problem one step in front of me?

Comment: 'name = "targetId"' in Category points to Category.targetId, right? Or should that be 'name = "id"' because it points to TranslationTargets.id, just like TranslationTarget's 'name = "targetId"' points to TranslatableText.targetId?

Comment: When doing this, I get the following exception. Is there something in the mappings I missed? com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'texts0_.targetId' in 'field list'

Comment: @niklassaers: `name` in `@ManyToOne`'s `@JoinColumn` points to the name of foreign key at the "many" side (i.e. `TranslatableText.targetId`), then in `@OneToOne` it points to the current side, i.e. `Category.targetId`.

Comment: @niklassaers: Note that I renamed `TranslatableText`'s `id` to `targetId`.

Comment: Thanks. With that sorted out, I still got a weird but when accessing the texts: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class tld.myproject.data.entities.TranslationTarget. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class [Ljava.lang.Object;   The class it got is an array of Longs with just one element. Any idea why this happens?